# Known Equality in Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Can someone explain to me the following equality in general normal distribution?

The left part is equal to $\phi(a)=\phi((a-\mu)/\sigma)$

The original version:

[image]

My lecturer just wrote it and said it's easy to concluded that...

Comment: Probably this is from just the definition / meaning of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $\displaystyle  \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} = Z \sim N(0,1)$

Or

If $Z \sim N(0,1)$ then $X = \sigma Z + \mu \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

So $\displaystyle \Phi (x) = P(X \le x) = P(\sigma Z + \mu \le x) = P(Z \le \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}) = \Phi(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})$